# how to Print data in listview in android

Tags: android

Here i am getting data on Console :

```
DataBaseManager dbManager = new DataBaseManager(context);
ArrayList<Notify> notifies = dbManager.getNotificationList();
System.out.println("today " + notifies.size());
for (int i = 0; i < notifies.size(); i++) {
    System.out
        .println("Valueeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee:"
                + notifies.get(i).getNotificationStatus()
                + "\n"
                + notifies.get(i).getNotificationServerId() + "\n" +
                notifies.get(i).getNotificationDatetime());

}
```

Here is my datamodelclass:

```
public class Notify {
    private String notificationId;
    private String notificationServerId;
    private String notificationSenderID;
    private String notificationRecieverID;
    private String notificationType;
    private String notificationDescrpiton;
    private String notificationStatus;
    private String notificationDatetime;
    private String notificationIsRead;

    public String getNotificationId() {
        return notificationId;
    }

    public void setNotificationId(String notificationId) {
        this.notificationId = notificationId;
    }

    public String getNotificationServerId() {
        return notificationServerId;
    }

    public void setNotificationServerId(String notificationServerId) {
        this.notificationServerId = notificationServerId;
    }

    public String getNotificationSenderID() {
        return notificationSenderID;
    }

    public void setNotificationSenderID(String notificationSenderID) {
        this.notificationSenderID = notificationSenderID;
    }

    public String getNotificationRecieverID() {
        return notificationRecieverID;
    }

    public void setNotificationRecieverID(String notificationRecieverID) {
        this.notificationRecieverID = notificationRecieverID;
    }

    public String getNotificationType() {
        return notificationType;
    }

    public void setNotificationType(String notificationType) {
        this.notificationType = notificationType;
    }

    public String getNotificationDescrpiton() {
        return notificationDescrpiton;
    }

    public void setNotificationDescrpiton(String notificationDescrpiton) {
        this.notificationDescrpiton = notificationDescrpiton;
    }

    public String getNotificationStatus() {
        return notificationStatus;
    }

    public void setNotificationStatus(String notificationStatus) {
        this.notificationStatus = notificationStatus;
    }

    public String getNotificationDatetime() {
        return notificationDatetime;
    }

    public void setNotificationDatetime(String notificationDatetime) {
        this.notificationDatetime = notificationDatetime;
    }

    public String getNotificationIsRead() {
        return notificationIsRead;
    }
```

Here is my  adapter:

```
public class RowItem extends BaseAdapter {

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

I want tp Print value In List i have 3 text view for

```
 notifies.get(i).getNotificationStatus()
 notifies.get(i).getNotificationStatus()
 notifies.get(i).getNotificationStatus()
```

But i am unable to Print data please help how to set value in adapter.

Comment: Have you set your data in DataBase class??? You have to pass `notifies` arraylist to your `RowItem`  adapter and in `getView()` method get your values.

Comment: yes am getting data in Log

Comment: So follow my comment

Comment: hello @PG_Android http://pastie.org/9518629,http://pastie.org/9518631 check this and tell me the solution

Comment: This page not going to open.

Comment: http://pastie.org/9518640 open this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you sending the `ArrayList` while creating **Object of Notifcationadapter** (inside Activity or Fragment) no need to fill data in `Notifcationadapter`. You should only declare the arraylist `ArrayList<Notify> notifies;`

Code

```
Context context;
ViewHolder holder;
//LinearLayout linear2;
ArrayList<Notify> notifies;
public Notifcationadapter(Context context,ArrayList<Notify> notifies) {
    super();
    this.context = context;
    this.notifies = notifies;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ViewHolder Class for that

Comment: This must be comment!!

Comment: @PG_Android tell solution

Comment: Move this code DataBaseManager dbManager = new DataBaseManager(context);
 ArrayList<Notify> notifies = dbManager.getNotificationList(); to your NotoficationAdapter constructor

Comment: @PG_Android : is this necessary? coz he is sending an `ArrayList` from `Activity` to `adapter`(P.S `public Notifcationadapter(Context context,ArrayList<Notify> notifies)`). He just need to assign that arraylist.

Comment: Yes but its context variable is null

Comment: please suggest me Solution man i am getting null Pointer exception

Comment: have you checked my comment?

Comment: YUp But i am unable to set value on adapter

Answer (score 0):

Why are you returning 0 to getCount();
fix your adapter-

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return notifies.size();
}

@Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return notifies.get(arg0);
    }

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return arg0;
}
```